# How many characters x can you add in a string so that no three consecutive characters exist within the string?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

This was a leetcode-esque interview question I tried a while back and didn't get very far, trying again now. Given a string, how many characters e.g 'b' can you input in the string so that no 3 consecutive 'b's exist within the string.

Example:

Given: `cat`

String: `bbcbbabbtbb`
Output: 8

Given `babb`

String: `bbabb`
Output: 1

Given `bb`

String: `bb`
Output: 0

My approach was a sliding window keeping track of 'b's in front of the current index, however I quickly got lost. My solution is probably far off but here it is:

```
def consecB(S):
    num = 0

    for i in range(0, len(S)-2):
        if S[i] == 'b':
            if S[i+1] == 'b':
                pass
            else:
                num += 1
                str_list += 'b'
            num +=1
        else:
            if S[i+1] == 'b':
                if S[i+2] == 'b':
                    pass
                else:
                    num += 1
            else:
                num += 2

    return num
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Thanks to the top answer I was able to work out a solution if anyone was wondering:

```
def consecB(S):
    num_of_b = S.count('b')
    return 2*((len(S)-num_of_b)+1) - num_of_b
```

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. Consider that if `'bbb' in mystring` is True then the output is always 0. Conversely if `'b' not in mystring` is True then the output is a function of the length of the string. So now you just need logic to handle the other 2 possible cases (1 or 2 `'b'`s)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's much simpler than you're making it.

A string that has no `b`s in it to begin with, can have two `b`s inserted between each other character, plus at the beginning and end. (In terms of the length of the string, how many is that?)

A string that has a single `b` will end up looking the same when "filled" with `b`s as if it didn't have that `b` in it. So it's as if we started with a string 1 character shorter (the original `b` doesn't give us an extra position to insert them) and also we can insert 1 fewer `b` because the one that was already there will take its place. So as a result, we insert (exercise: how many?) fewer `b`s than if the character were not a `b`.

This extends to any number of isolated `b`s.

If there is a double `b`, then it removes two places to insert: compare inserting into `acbbca` to inserting in `acca`. Either way we get `bbabbcbbcbbabb`; the principle is the same - we start with a string 2 characters shorter and insert 2 fewer `b`s because they were already there. That is to say, it doesn't matter whether the original `b`s were isolated or doubled up; each `b` in the original string reduces the answer by the same amount.

In conclusion, a simple mathematical formula - in terms of the length of the string and the number of `b`s already present - tells us the answer. (Of course, if there is already a triple `b` then we cannot add to the string at all, so we should sanity-check for that separately).

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, one insight makes this trivial.  First, check that you do *not* already have three consecutive `b`s in the string; if so, you're sunk -- the final string must fail the basic test.

With that out of the way, your final, maximal string will be pairs of `b`s as separators and bookends for the non-`b` characters.  So ...

- Count the quantity of non-`b` characters; call this `n`.  Your final string will be those `n` characters, plus `2*(n+1)` buffering `b`s.
- The quantity of `b`s to *add* is `2*(n+1) - (len(s) - n)`, where `s` is the original string.

Comment: Quite correct.  I had that in mind, but dropped my mental sticky-note.  Thanks ... edited.